# python autocomplete for dynamic class creation

Tags: python, python-3.x, autocomplete, pycharm

suppose I have the following code in `main.py`:

```
obj = parser.parse()
```

and the `parser.py` as follows:

```
class parser:
    def parse(self):
        for choice in range(0, 10):
            dynamic_class_name = "A" + str(choice)
            x = type(dynamic_class_name , (), {'val' : 10})
            setattr(self, dynamic_class_name, x)
```

In my `main.py`
I want to have the option to see the autocomplete.
for example, for:

```
obj = parser.parse()
```

After that line, if I type `obj` again, I want `PyCharm` to suggest the autocompletion of 
`A1, A2, A3, A4,...` and so on.

How is that possible?

Comment: These are attributes that exist during runtime, why would you expect PyCharm be able to discern their existence statically?

Comment: @JimFasarakisHilliard I agree with you, I still wonder if there is a workaround here.

Comment: @JimFasarakisHilliard maybe it's possible to run a preprocess script or create a small plugin for it?

Comment: @ranifisch: I am looking for same thing as you asked. Have you got any workaround for this ?